# Erro CS0030 - Cannot convert type ' ' to 'double'

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-cli

Boa noite, estou com um erro no meu código e não estou conseguinfo resolver.

Tenho a segunte função abaixo:

```
public static double SomaTotalProdutos(List<Produto> produtos)
{
    double totalProdutos = 0.0;
    foreach (double precoP in produtos)
    {
        return totalProdutos += precoP
    }
    return totalProdutos;
```

Minha classe Produto esta da seguinte forma:

```
public class Produto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Preco { get; set; }

    public Produto()
    {
    }

    public Produto(string nome, double preco)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Preco = preco;
    }
}
```

O erro se dá bem no foreach, alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Comment: `precoP` (no foreach) é do tipo `Produto` e não `double`.

Comment: Fiz um double.Parse no preçoP, mas continua erro de convesão

Comment: Sim, porque esse parse não faz sentido.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

precoP é um Produto, então faça:

```
foreach (Produto p in produtos)
    {
        totalProdutos += p.Preco
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).